# Sufficient condition for 'fast' convergence of random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Consider a sequence $(X_n)_n$ of random variables. I'm interested in conditions under which, for each $\epsilon > 0$,

\begin{align}
\lim_{n \longrightarrow \infty} n P( |X_n-X| > \epsilon \sqrt{n} ) = 0.
\end{align}

In particular, I wonder if the result will hold if
$\lim\limits_{n \longrightarrow \infty} E[ |X_n-X|^2] = k,$
for some (non random) $k$. The 'standard' idea of using Chebyshev's inequality doesn't help here.

Do you have any suggestions on how to proceed? Thanks alot!

Comment: By Markov (by the way, you are missing a $-X$ in the absolute value, in your first inequality; otherwise, what you want will not hold):$$n\mathbb{P}\{\lvert X_n -X\rvert > \varepsilon\sqrt{n}\}=n\mathbb{P}\{\lvert X_n -X\rvert^2 > \varepsilon^2 n\} \leq n\frac{\mathbb{E}[\lvert X_n -X\rvert^2]}{\varepsilon^2 n} = \frac{\mathbb{E}[\lvert X_n -X\rvert^2]}{\varepsilon^2}$$ doesn't that suffice?

Comment: @ClementC. Yes, of course, thank you. I will edit it right away!

Comment: @ClementC. Yes, you are right. I'm afraid I misspecified the question completely. New edit pending. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: The condition you mention in your question is not sufficient. Just consider $X_n := \sqrt{n} 1_{(0,1/n)}$ on $(0,1)$ endowed with Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by saz, the condition $\lim\limits_{n \longrightarrow \infty} E[ |X_n-X|^2] = k$ is general not sufficient, as the example $X_n=\sqrt n\mathbf 1_{(0,1/n)}$ shows, where the involved probability space is the unit interval endowed with Borel $\sigma$-algebra and Lebesgue measure.

In general, uniform integrability of the family $\left(\left(X_n-X\right)^2,n\geqslant 1\right\}$ is sufficient, because 
$$
n P( |X_n-X| > \epsilon \sqrt{n} )\leqslant n\frac{1}{\left(\sqrt n\epsilon\right)^2}\mathbb E\left[\left(X_n-X\right)^2\mathbf 1\left\{\left\lvert X_n-X\right\rvert\gt\epsilon\sqrt n\right\}\right]\\  \leqslant \frac 1{\epsilon^2}
\sup_{k\geqslant 1}\mathbb E\left[\left(X_k-X\right)^2\mathbf 1\left\{\left\lvert X_k-X\right\rvert\gt\epsilon\sqrt n\right\}\right].
$$